# how to get column names in pandas of getdummies

Tags: python, pandas

After i created a data frame and make the function get_dummies on my dataframe:

```
df_final=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['type'])
```

I got the new columns that I want and everything is working.

My question is, how can I get the new columns names of the get dummies? my dataframe is dynamic so I can't call is staticly, I wish to save all the new columns names on List.

Comment: `df_final.columns` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be:

```py
df_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=target_cols)
df_dummy.columns.difference(df.columns).tolist()
```

where `df` is your original dataframe, `df_dummy` the output from `pd.get_dummies`, and `target_cols` your list of columns to get the dummies.

Comment: hey, is target cols is my columns ['type']?